# Suppose $\lim_n e^{itb_n}$ exists for all $|t|\le \delta$, show that $\limsup |b_n| < \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

I would like some help with the following:

> Let $(b_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\lim_n e^{itb_n}$ exists for all $|t|\le \delta$, $\delta >0$. Show that $\limsup |b_n| < \infty$.

**Edit:** as per *Mindlack*'s hint, below is an attempt to a solution.

---

For each $n$ define
$$
f_n(t) = e^{itb_n}, \quad |t| < \delta.
$$
Then, by assumption, $(f_n(t))_n$ converges for every $|t|\le \delta$. Obviously each $f_n$ is square integrable since
$$
\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \left | f_n \right |^2 \, d \mu = \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} 1 \, d \mu = 2\delta.
$$
As pointwise convergence implies convergence in $L^2$, and $L^2([-t,t], \mu)$ is a complete metric space, the limit is also square integrable.

To calculate the Fourier transform of this limit, one may use the Dominated convergence theorem.
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} e^{-2 \pi it \xi}\lim_n f_n(t) \, d \mu(t) &= \lim_n\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} e^{-2 \pi it \xi}f_n(t) \, d \mu(t) \\
&= \lim_n\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} e^{-2 \pi it \xi}e^{itb_n} \, d \mu(t) \\
&= \lim_n\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} e^{it(b_n -2 \pi \xi)}\, d \mu(t)\\
&= \lim_n \left (\frac{e^{i\delta(b_n -2 \pi \xi)}}{i(b_n -2 \pi \xi)} - \frac{e^{-i\delta(b_n -2 \pi \xi)}}{i(b_n -2 \pi \xi)} \right ) \\
&= \lim_n \frac{2i \sin(\delta(b_n -2 \pi \xi))}{i(b_n -2 \pi \xi)} \\
&= \lim_n \frac{2 \sin(\delta(b_n -2 \pi \xi))}{b_n -2 \pi \xi}.
\end{align*}

> I'm not sure what conclusion I could draw from this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, close requests: what isn't that does not meet the expectations?

Comment: This is a "Problem statement question".  It includes nothing of your own effort/thoughts/attempts.  That's what we are looking for

Comment: Okey, I get that! My problem is that I simply does not know how to approach this. But I will try to add something!

Comment: Hint: let $f_n(t)=e^{itb_n}$ for $|t| \leq \delta$. Then $f_n(t)$ converges in $L^2$ to some function $g$. What is the Fourier transform of $g$?

Comment: Okey, so following the hint from Mindlack, I did an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $f\in L_1$, denote by $\hat{f}$ its Fourier transform.

In your notation, let $g(t)=\lim_n f_n(t)$, where $f_n(t)=e^{ib_n t}\mathbb{1}_{[-\delta,\delta]}(t)$. Each $f_n\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\|f_n\|_1=2\delta>0$. Then by dominated convergence $\|g\|_1=2\delta>0$.
Suppose there is a subsequence $|b_{n_k}|\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. Then (dominated convergence)
$$\hat{g}(\xi)=\lim_k\hat{f_{n_k}}(t)=2\lim_k\frac{\sin\big((b_{n_k}-2\pi\xi)\delta\big)}{b_{n_k}-2\pi\xi}=0$$
This means that $g(t)\equiv0$, contradicting the fact that $\|g\|_1>0$.

---

One can also extend $f_n$ as $2\delta$-periodic functions and use Fourier series instead, The ideas is similar. The $m$-th Fourier coefficient of $g$ is  the limit of the $m$-th Fourier coefficient of $f_n$. Arguing as before, you get that $g\equiv0$ and get a contradiction to the positivity of $\|g\|_{L_2(\mathbb{T}^1)
}$.